# Subclass object not showing parent class variable in swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, swift-protocols

I am facing this weird problem and not sure why.
I have a class `View` which has a delegate variable of a protocol:

```
class View: UIView {
    weak var delegate : SampleProtocol?
}

protocol SampleProtocol: Class { }
```

Now this `View` class is the parent class of another class:

```
class AnotherView : View
```

When I am creating an `IBOutlet` of `AnotherView` in an Objective-C class it is not able to access the `delegate` variable and not visible in swift.h file either.

Could somebody explain what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Try using @objc, also make your protocol subclass from NSObject `protocol SampleProtocol: NSObject { }`

Comment: `class` should be lowercase for one

Comment: Also `sampleProtocol` should be capitalized in the `delegate` declaration

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need define your protocol readable by Objective-C adding `@objc` as I said in my comments

```
@objc protocol SampleProtocol: class { }
```

After that you have to add this line in your **.m**

```
#import "YourProjectName-Swift.h"
```

**Full code**

```
import UIKit

@objc protocol SampleProtocol: class { }

class View: UIView {
    weak var delegate : SampleProtocol?
}

class AnotherView : View{

}
```

**Heritage part have no side effects, was tested**

Now you can access to delegate property of your `View` class without any problem as is showed in this picture

[image]